# How to Upload file in selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to upload the file in selenium using java. When I run my test case then it passed every time but the file is not uploading. See below site and my code where I performing.

Site URL: https://files.fm/

Xpath where i want to upload: //input[@name='file_upload[]']

Note: If this xpath is incorrect then please update in comment.

Code:

```
@BeforeTest
public void OpenBrowser() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./driver/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://files.fm/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void FileUpload() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement file = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='file_upload[]']"));
    file.sendKeys("C:/Users/Admin/Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code :

```
WebElement file = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='file_upload']//following-sibling::input"));
file.sendKeys("C:/Users/Admin/Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg");

WebElement startUploadButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='savefiles']//div"));
startUploadButton.click();
```

Hope that helps you:)

Comment: Working this.. But not understand why using "//following-sibling::input".

Comment: it means just next element in HTML i.e input tag just next to input[@id='file_upload'] where we are sending the file using sendKeys.

Comment: Ok got you. Thanks, it will help in other xpath as well.

Comment: I have one more question, currently, I have taken a static path of my system but if I want to upload some other file which is in another driver so is this possible to open the window dynamically anyhow? Because its a static way to upload the file.

Comment: you can add filepaths in a properties file and can get them as a string whenever you require. to open a window see AutoIt script of doing this. for reference : https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

You choosed the wrong input. I tried to send to the other input and it worked

Here is xpath of it.

```
String inPath = "//*[@id='uploadifive-file_upload']/input[2]";
```

Comment: Working with this xpath as well. Thanks